# TypeError: property 1 is non-configurable and can't be deleted

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

For the below page,

```
<body>
    <form name="testForm" action="webtunings.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="city">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <form action="test.php" method="post" id="id1">
        <input type="radio" name="isCorrect" value="yes" >
        <input type="radio" name="isCorrect" value="no">
    </form>
</body>
```

---

Below code,

```
> var obj = document.getElementsByTagName('form')
    undefined
> obj
    HTMLCollection [ <form>, <form#id1> ]
> Array.prototype.pop.call(obj);
```

gives error: `TypeError: property 1 is non-configurable and can't be deleted`

Below code successfully deletes `form` element,

```
> var obj = document.getElementById("id1")
    undefined
> obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj)
```

---

Using `Array.prototype.pop`, Why browser says non-configurable property of `obj` unlike second approach?

Comment: Are you calling your functions **after** DOM has been completely rendered?

Comment: yes, am trying this code on devtool console after DOM is loaded

Comment: @overexchange Try: `obj.pop()`. Am I missing something stupid?

Comment: @PraveenKumar  `obj` in `var obj = document.getElementsByTagName ('form')` is not inheriting `Array.prototype`, so how would you call `pop`?

Comment: @overexchange Oh... I didn't know that the `HTMLCollection` is not inheriting `Array`. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why you would use pop, but `[].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('form')).pop()`

Comment: @epascarello When I say `Array.prototype.pop.call(obj)`, why `pop` does not work on array like object `obj`? unlike `slice`?

Comment: @overexchange May be convert it to a proper array first then apply `pop()`?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML collection contains a live list of form elements in the DOM.

If you remove a form from the DOM then the list will automatically update.

You can't remove the element directly from the list. It is designed to forbid that.